# How to count the number of lists in a binary file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to count the number of lists in my binary file for a project that I have made, so that I can print my previously stored data but I receive an EOF error. Can you tell me why?

```
import pickle
F=open('binary_file_1.dat','rb')
while True:
    List=pickle.load(F)
    l=l+1
F.close()
print('l=',l)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\program_x.py", line 7, in <module>List=pickle.load(F)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Open to all suggestions. Thank you, readers

Comment: If the serialised object is a Python class, you can introspect __dict__ to determine what types of attributes are contained within it

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Oh actually I was given a list of lists so I don't need to figure out the datatype but thanks. If you know the answer please let me know

Comment: Can you show what the object looks like that you serialised (pickled). Was it a single class?

Comment: I also finally devised a way ,my list looked liked this [Milk,2,100,40] which shows the item name, discount and other related numbers. So, to count such lists I made this code ```count=1
F=open('binary_file_1.dat','rb')
Y=F.readlines()
for x in Y:
    z=len(x)
    for q in range(z-1):
        if x[q:q+1]==b'.':
            count=count+1
F.close()``` Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `pickle.load()` in for loop. When loading pickled file you get the same object you saved with `pickle.dump()`, so if your object was for example list of lists, you could use `len(pickle.load(f))` to get number of lists, or something similar based on object type.

Comment: So sorry but I I think you misunderstood me, I actually wanted to count the number of lists and not the number of elements of the list. Can you resolve my problem now

Comment: Even the cursor doesn't come out of the while loop  if it's false in python.3-x, it just shows EOF error